# Modeling Lotka-Volterra equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

Consider the case $a < b c$ in the Lotka-Volterra equations for the rabbits and foxes
$\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}$
\begin{align}
\frac{\dd R}{\dd t} &= (a − b R − F )R,
\\
\frac{\dd F}{\dd t}  &= ( –c + R)F.
\end{align}
Sketch the phase plane and use it to determine the populations as $t → ∞$.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Have you detected the meaning of the parameter condition?